# Implementing a depth-first tree iterator in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, iterator, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement an iterator class for not-necessarily-binary trees in Python. After the iterator is constructed with a tree's root node, its `next()` function can be called repeatedly to traverse the tree in depth-first order (e.g., [this order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#mediaviewer/File:Depth-first-tree.svg)), finally returning `None` when there are no nodes left.

Here is the basic `Node` class for a tree:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, title, children=None):
        self.title = title
        self.children = children or []
        self.visited = False   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

As you can see above, I introduced a `visited` property to the nodes for my first approach, since I didn't see a way around it. With that extra measure of state, the `Iterator` class looks like this:

```
class Iterator(object):

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.stack = []
        self.current = root

    def next(self):
        if self.current is None:
            return None

        self.stack.append(self.current)
        self.current.visited = True

        # Root case
        if len(self.stack) == 1:
            return self.current

        while self.stack:
            self.current = self.stack[-1] 
            for child in self.current.children:
                if not child.visited:
                    self.current = child
                    return child

            self.stack.pop()
```

This is all well and good, but I want to get rid of the need for the `visited` property, without resorting to recursion or any other alterations to the `Node` class.

All the state I need should be taken care of in the iterator, but I'm at a loss about how that can be done. Keeping a visited list for the whole tree is non-scalable and out of the question, so there must be a clever way to use the stack.

What especially confuses me is this--since the `next()` function, of course, returns, how can I remember where I've been without marking anything or using excess storage? Intuitively, I think of looping over children, but that logic is broken/forgotten when the `next()` function returns!

UPDATE - Here is a small test:

```
tree = Node(
    'A', [
        Node('B', [
            Node('C', [
                Node('D')
                ]),
            Node('E'),
            ]),
        Node('F'),
        Node('G'),
        ])

iter = Iterator(tree)

out = object()
while out:
    out = iter.next()
    print out
```

Comment: Keeping a visited *list* might be non-scalable, but what about a visited set, e.g. based on Node object id?

Comment: That could still potentially hold every label, though. I want the iterator to keep only a subset of the tree at a time.

Comment: What is the expected output of the "small test"?

Comment: It should give `A B C D E F G None` . BTW, implementing @mgilson's generator solutions as the `next()` bodies results in an infinite loop, but that might just be my poor adaptation/understanding of generators.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're trying to do it, but I've updated my answer to show it passing your tests... (Note that I've coded it assuming that you'd traverse it in a `for` loop, not some sort of while loop.  I don't see your while loop working anywhere since you don't catch the `StopIteration` exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really must avoid recursion, this iterator works:

```
from collections import deque

def node_depth_first_iter(node):
    stack = deque([node])
    while stack:
        # Pop out the first element in the stack
        node = stack.popleft()
        yield node
        # push children onto the front of the stack.
        # Note that with a deque.extendleft, the first on in is the last
        # one out, so we need to push them in reverse order.
        stack.extendleft(reversed(node.children))
```

---

With that said, I think that you're thinking about this too hard.  A good-ole' (recursive) generator also does the trick:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, title, children=None):
        self.title = title
        self.children = children or []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            for node in child:
                yield node
```

both of these pass your tests:

```
expected = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
# Test recursive generator using Node.__iter__
assert [str(n) for n in tree] == expected

# test non-recursive Iterator
assert [str(n) for n in node_depth_first_iter(tree)] == expected
```

and you can easily make `Node.__iter__` use the non-recursive form if you prefer:

```
def __iter__(self):
   return node_depth_first_iter(self)
```

Comment: `stack = queue` and all operations to the left. Why not just stack and pop \ append ?

Answer (score 0):

> That could still potentially hold every label, though. I want the
>   iterator to keep only a subset of the tree at a time.

But you already *are* holding everything. Remember that an object is essentially a dictionary with an entry for each attribute. Having `self.visited = False` in the `__init__` of `Node` means you are storing a redundant `"visited"` key and `False` value for every single `Node` object no matter what. A set, at least, also has the potential of *not* holding every single node ID. Try this:

```
class Iterator(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.visited_ids = set()
        ...

    def next(self):
        ...
        #self.current.visited = True
        self.visited_ids.add(id(self.current))
        ...
                #if not child.visited:
                if id(child) not in self.visited_ids:
```

Looking up the ID in the set should be just as fast as accessing a node's attribute. The only way this can be more wasteful than your solution is the overhead of the set object itself (not its elements), which is only a concern if you have multiple concurrent iterators (which you obviously don't, otherwise the node `visited` attribute couldn't be useful to you).